# How can XML belongs to layout of app

Tags: android, xml

I am new with XML and android. as we know XML store , carry , and exchange data. but the activity_main file (in eclipse) has file extension of XML, and also the first line of code belongs to XML but not remaining. what i don't understand is that what is the relation of XML with the layout of app?

Comment: The file is called `.xml` because it is an XML file. Not sure what you are looking at, but the file is not only in the first line, but it is actually completely xml.

Comment: you need to read the docs.

Comment: this is the first line of code.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> and also if i remove this line so the layout still works?

Answer (score 1):

XML is a document format, not a file exchange mechanism. HTTP is a "transfer protocol" for example. You can exchange all kinds of files, including XML files.

XML stands for "eXtensible Markup Language" and it allows us to build a structured file that both people and computers can read pretty easily. This is very different from "encoded files" like an APK where a computer can read it easily and a person cannot.

The XML allows us to create screen layouts using commonly occurring and fairly static elements. So you can puts text and headers on the screen without using Java. More complex elements, like data lists or dynamically loaded images, require Java.

In particular this is a huge feature of Android because app designers (more visually skilled and less "programmer") can create displays while people that are less visually gifted but more gifted writing code, can develop the complex interactions and back-end heavy lifting.

Here's the Android docs on XML:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

And here's tutorial explaining XML vs dynamic layouts:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/android-dynamic-and-xml-layout.html

Many developers prefer one over the other - I like XML and use it when I can, but knowing how to build dynamic UI is critical to good app development.

Comment: thanks alot Jim. i got your answer.

Comment: i got your answer. dear please if you suggest me some best sources,as i am new with android and java. so from where should i take start? i mean any reliable source?.

Comment: I edited my comment. Hope it helps